# railo soap service name

Tags: soap, coldfusion, railo

I am moving my SOAP webservice from a ColdFusion to a Railo server.
However, the name of my SOAP-webservice changes in Railo, which causes errors at the servers that consume this service.

From the wsdl generated by Railo:
<wsdl:service name="**FMSService_wrapService**">

Same service in ColdFusion
<wsdl:service name="**FMSServiceService**">

Is there a way to change the service's name manually?

I tried this in the webservice's cfc:
<cfcomponent name="FMSService"...

It didn't work...

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: Could be an incompatibility issue. Consider moving to Railo's successor Lucee (you should do that anyway) and report it.

Comment: Are you using any sort of framework that may be intercepting the request here?